# About the boundedness of the derivative of a function which is in special function space.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

If $f \in C^1 ([0,T] , L^2)  \cap C^0 ([0,T] , W^{1,2} )$, then how can I conclude that $$ \left \| \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} \right \|_{L^\infty([0,T] \times \Bbb R^n )} < \infty ?$$ 
Here $f$ is defined on $[0,T] \times \Bbb R^n$ , and the notation $f \in C^1([0,T], L^2)$ means that $\| f(t) \|_{L^2 (\Bbb R^n)}$ is continuously differentiable on $[0,T]$, $W^{s,p}$ means the usual Sobolev space.

Comment: Handwaving: $\partial f/\partial t = \mathrm df/\mathrm dt - \partial f/\partial x\ \partial x/\partial t$, thus the first inclusion gives (ess.) finiteness for the first term on the rhs, the second gives (ess.) finiteness for the second term, thus their difference is also essentially finite.

Comment: @filmor Thank you, but here $x$ is not depend on $t$. $f = f(t,x_1 , \cdots , x_n)$.

Comment: I don't think this is true: Take $f(t,x)=t\eta(x)|x|^{n-\alpha}$ with $\eta\in C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ a cut-off function, then for a suitable $\alpha>0$ we have $f\in W^{1,2}$, but $\eta(x)|x|^{n-\alpha}\notin L^{\infty}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I am missing something, this does not seem to be correct. Let $n=3$, and define $$ F(x) = \|x\|^{-1/3} \quad\text{ for $\|x\|\le 1$,} $$
and extend it smoothly to a function with compact support on $\mathbb{R}^3$. Then
$$ \|\nabla F(x)\| = \frac13 \|x\|^{-4/3} \quad\text{ for $\|x\|\le 1$},$$
so $F \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$, $\nabla F \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$ and thus $F\in W^{1,2}(\mathbb{R}^3)$. Now define
 $$f(t,x) = t F(x). $$ Then $$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} (t,x) = F(x), $$
so this example seems to satisfy the even stronger assumption that $f \in C^1([0,T],W^{1,2})$, but it $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} = F \notin L^\infty$.

Comment: The Sobolev embedding doesn't give that inclusion: Take $f(x)=\log\log(1+|x|^{-1})$.

Comment: Jose27, thanks, I deleted the wrong comment.

Comment: Thank you very much. But how it becomes if we add the additional assumption: $f(t,x)$ is bounded on $[0,T] \times \Bbb R^n$ ?